# How to define a custom CamelBeanPostProcessor with Camel 2.9

Tags: spring, apache-camel

Camel uses the [CamelBeanPostProcessor](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-spring/apidocs/org/apache/camel/spring/CamelBeanPostProcessor.html) class to support autowiring of camel endpoints, producer templates etc into beans using annotations.

The documentation for the class says:

> If you use the  element in your Spring XML then one of
>   these bean post processors is implicitly installed and configured for
>   you. So you should never have to explicitly create or configure one of
>   these instances.

but no mention on how to actually provide a custom implementation.

I use Spring and the `<camelContext...>` way of configuring camel. How do I provide my own implementation of CamelBeanPostProcessor, that way? The reason is I want to override the `canPostProcessBean` method to exclude a couple of bean types as post processing them causes a problem for us. They will never have any camel features in them, so it is not a problem.

Comment: I have been thinking... what about AOP to the `postProcessBeforeInitialization`? You could make an aspect to avoid the method invocation based on your needs...

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to define your own BeanPostProcessor. As stated by the [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html):

> ApplicationContexts can autodetect BeanPostProcessor beans in their
>   bean definitions and apply them to any beans subsequently created.
>   Plain bean factories allow for programmatic registration of
>   post-processors, applying to all beans created through this factory.

So, if you use the camel xml like this:

```
<camel:beanPostProcessor/>
```

Just replace with:

```
<bean id="camel:beanPostProcessor"
        class="org.mael.sample.camel.postprocessor.CustomCamelBeanPostProcessor" />
```

This way you will not use the CamelBeanPostProcessor registered by the xml, but your own BeanPostProcessor implementation.

But beware if you want to extend the CamelBeanPostProcessor class, I have seen the [source](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/camel/camel-spring/2.3.0/camel-spring-2.3.0-sources.jar!/org/apache/camel/spring/CamelBeanPostProcessor.java?format=ok) and it uses an instance of [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelBeanPostProcessor](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-spring/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/spring/CamelBeanPostProcessor.java) as a delegate and extend the later will cause some errors because the exceptions thrown do not match with the exceptions declared in the Spring interfaces.

The best option would be to use also a delegate in your own implementation and just override the methods you want i.e. `canPostProcessBean`

EDIT:

Here is something I did, check for the `TODO` comment for applying your functionality, also, [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/XtDiREPQ):

```
package org.mike.sample.camel.postprocessor;

import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Endpoint;
import org.apache.camel.Service;
import org.apache.camel.core.xml.CamelJMXAgentDefinition;
import org.apache.camel.impl.CamelPostProcessorHelper;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelBeanPostProcessor;
import org.apache.camel.spring.GenericBeansException;
import org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

public class CustomCamelBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor,
        ApplicationContextAware {

    private static final transient Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(CustomCamelBeanPostProcessor.class);
    @XmlTransient
    Set<String> prototypeBeans = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    @XmlTransient
    private CamelContext camelContext;
    @XmlTransient
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @XmlTransient
    private String camelId;

    // must use a delegate, as we cannot extend DefaultCamelBeanPostProcessor,
    // as this will cause the
    // XSD schema generator to include the DefaultCamelBeanPostProcessor as a
    // type, which we do not want to
    @XmlTransient
    private final DefaultCamelBeanPostProcessor delegate = new DefaultCamelBeanPostProcessor() {
        @Override
        public CamelContext getOrLookupCamelContext() {
            if (camelContext == null) {
                if (camelId != null) {
                    LOG.trace(
                            "Looking up CamelContext by id: {} from Spring ApplicationContext: {}",
                            camelId, applicationContext);
                    camelContext = applicationContext.getBean(camelId,
                            CamelContext.class);
                } else {
                    // lookup by type and grab the single CamelContext if exists
                    LOG.trace(
                            "Looking up CamelContext by type from Spring ApplicationContext: {}",
                            applicationContext);
                    Map<String, CamelContext> contexts = applicationContext
                            .getBeansOfType(CamelContext.class);
                    if (contexts != null && contexts.size() == 1) {
                        camelContext = contexts.values().iterator().next();
                    }
                }
            }
            return camelContext;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canPostProcessBean(Object bean, String beanName) {
            // the JMXAgent is a bit strange and causes Spring issues if we let
            // it being
            // post processed by this one. It does not need it anyway so we are
            // good to go.
            // We should also avoid to process the null object bean (in Spring
            // 2.5.x)

            // TODO - DO YOUR STUFF HERE STRELOK

            if (bean == null || bean instanceof CamelJMXAgentDefinition) {
                return false;
            }

            return super.canPostProcessBean(bean, beanName);
        }

        @Override
        public CamelPostProcessorHelper getPostProcessorHelper() {
            // lets lazily create the post processor
            if (camelPostProcessorHelper == null) {
                camelPostProcessorHelper = new CamelPostProcessorHelper() {

                    @Override
                    public CamelContext getCamelContext() {
                        // lets lazily lookup the camel context here
                        // as doing this will cause this context to be started
                        // immediately
                        // breaking the lifecycle ordering of different camel
                        // contexts
                        // so we only want to do this on demand
                        return delegate.getOrLookupCamelContext();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected RuntimeException createProxyInstantiationRuntimeException(
                            Class<?> type, Endpoint endpoint, Exception e) {
                        return new BeanInstantiationException(type,
                                "Could not instantiate proxy of type "
                                        + type.getName() + " on endpoint "
                                        + endpoint, e);
                    }

                    protected boolean isSingleton(Object bean, String beanName) {
                        // no application context has been injected which means
                        // the bean
                        // has not been enlisted in Spring application context
                        if (applicationContext == null || beanName == null) {
                            return super.isSingleton(bean, beanName);
                        } else {
                            return applicationContext.isSingleton(beanName);
                        }
                    }

                    protected void startService(Service service, Object bean,
                            String beanName) throws Exception {
                        if (isSingleton(bean, beanName)) {
                            getCamelContext().addService(service);
                        } else {
                            // only start service and do not add it to
                            // CamelContext
                            ServiceHelper.startService(service);
                            if (prototypeBeans.add(beanName)) {
                                // do not spam the log with WARN so do this only
                                // once per bean name
                                CustomCamelBeanPostProcessor.LOG
                                        .warn("The bean with id ["
                                                + beanName
                                                + "] is prototype scoped and cannot stop the injected service when bean is destroyed: "
                                                + service
                                                + ". You may want to stop the service manually from the bean.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
            return camelPostProcessorHelper;
        }
    };

    public CustomCamelBeanPostProcessor() {
    }

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        try {
            return delegate.postProcessBeforeInitialization(bean, beanName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do not wrap already beans exceptions
            if (e instanceof BeansException) {
                throw (BeansException) e;
            }
            throw new GenericBeansException("Error post processing bean: "
                    + beanName, e);
        }
    }

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        try {
            return delegate.postProcessAfterInitialization(bean, beanName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do not wrap already beans exceptions
            if (e instanceof BeansException) {
                throw (BeansException) e;
            }
            throw new GenericBeansException("Error post processing bean: "
                    + beanName, e);
        }
    }

    // Properties
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public CamelContext getCamelContext() {
        return camelContext;
    }

    public void setCamelContext(CamelContext camelContext) {
        this.camelContext = camelContext;
    }

    public String getCamelId() {
        return camelId;
    }

    public void setCamelId(String camelId) {
        this.camelId = camelId;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes that was my first instinct as well. The bean name is actually `<contextName>:beanPostProcessor`. But creating a bean `camelContext:beanPostProcessor` does little else but register and _extra_ Spring post processor, in addition to the one automatically registered by Camel.

Comment: So, there is two or just one if you skip `<camel:beanPostProcessor/>` in your xml config?

Comment: `<camel:beanPostProcessor/>` is not supported anymore (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-3724), a post processor gets registered automatically inside `CamelNamespaceHandler`. So when a bean with a name camelContext:beanPostProcessor is also registered you actually get 2 post processors. After some time looking at `CamelNamespaceHandler` source, it seems that it is not possible to do what I want via xml.